# Drupal 7 - Redirect to node according to location input

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a special request on drupal 7, my client wants me to create a form input where he can enter a Swiss postal code, it could be any as long as it exists and redirect to pages according to the number in that input.

The problem is that I have no idea on how I'll do it, which module can help me in order to do that, there are more than 2000 postal codes is there also a Google Maps module that can know which code comes from which regions ?

I am facing 2 issues, an input that can redirect to a special page according to the code and a module that can recognize the postal code and find in which regions it belongs?

Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you basically need

1. A map Swiss postal code to Swiss regions (could be in the database, or using an external tool/service)
2. A map of Swiss regions to pages on your site.
3. A form letting the user enter their postal code and redirect them to the page mapped to its region on submit.

AFAIK, this could not be build with existing module and you would have to create a custom module for that.

To map content to regions: Create a "Region" taxonomy vocabulary, with one term for each region. Then add a taxonomy reference fields to your page content type.

[Create custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7), with a custom form (using the [Form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/37775)) create you form (as a block, or as a page) and in the submit handler for that form, have code to map the input to a region, find the first content (a `node` entity) associated with the region (using [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)) and redirect to it.